# Praat: CPP from modified .Manipulation file

Tags: phonetics, praat, acoustic-analysis

I am working with dysphonic speech and Praat's automated pulse detection algorithm is inadequate, so I manually correct the placement of pulses using .Manipulation files.

My ultimate goal is to measure CPP: I know how to obtain this measure from an original unmodified Sound file. However, when I try to resynthesize (either with overlap-add or LPC) the modified .Manipulation file, the resulting Sound file doesn't exhibit the same pulses as my manually corrected .Manipulation file does.

I tried reading the Praat documentation, but couldn't find an answer there or from web searches, nor could I find any previous StackExchange questions addressing this questions, so I hope somebody can advise me on what I may be missing.

Comment: How did you make those changes? You should have extracted the `PointProcess` object and made your changes on this object. Then you can apply these changes back to the `Manipulation` object with `Replace pulses`. Is this what you did?